# Symfony2 assets without Assetic?

Tags: symfony, gruntjs, assetic, asset-management

My question is simple: I want to manage the assets by Grunt, can Assetic be left out of a Symfony2 app and have it function correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a solution for your task – [Symfony Grunt Edition](https://github.com/kbond/symfony-grunt-edition).

Comment: Thank you for the link! It gave me some starting points. Though it only gave me half solution: how to deal with vendor bundles that come with their own assets? (this gives me the biggest headache so far)